# Click on rendered item in select field?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In material-ui it is possible to render an element within a `Select` component.
I'd love to render a `Chip` within a select component. But I'd also love to be able to click on the chip and trigger an `onClick` handler.

I can't seem to figure out how to make the chip clickable, though. Every click seems to trigger the containing select element.

I created a CodeSandBox to demonstrate my problem.

https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-wu-efiwk?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I achieve to make the chip clickable by putting the z-index of the chip higher than the select element. Maybe try to do that.

Comment: tried that. didn't work.

Comment: Danila's answer is sufficient on its own, but in case you'd like to know, you need a z-index of at least 1301 to bring it to the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `onMouseDown` handler to your Chip component and use `stopPropagation` there because `Select` listens to `mousedown` event.

```
onMouseDown={e => {
  e.stopPropagation();
}}
```